# Do certain materials link to certain stats? Like items of Mica seem to always boost luck by 3?

Tags: elona-plus, elona

Do certain materials link to certain stats? Like items of Mica seem to always boost luck by 3?

Or is it just luck that I've seen two mica rings and they boost Luck, and the [Epeclair](https://elona.fandom.com/wiki/Epeclair) of Elona+ is mica and also boosts luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, materials affect the effects of items, and Mica has Luck +3 as one, as said on the Wiki's section for [Material Types of Equipment](https://elona.fandom.com/wiki/Equipment#Material_Types).

You just had to use a different search engine. Google has it in the first page, if you searched "Mica Luck Elona".